# Override config values Symfony QueueBundle

Tags: php, symfony, queue

I am using QueueBundle in Symfony https://github.com/nicholasnet/QueueBundle however I am trying to use different/override config values for my dev environment for connections. Is there anyway to do that. Currently my config.yml looks somewhat like this.

```
ideasbucket_queue:
    cache_handler: app.cache
    default: beanstalkd
    connections:
        beanstalkd:
            driver: beanstalkd
            queue: prod
            .....
```

I want to override queue name for dev environment. I was able to override other values but nothing inside connection. Is there anyway to do that. I am using Symfony 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved in recent version 1.0.4. Now you can overwrite default connection configuration per environment. If for any reason its not working then please feel free to create an issue.